How to disable IntelliJ HTML tab autocomplete in JavaScript?
To reproduce:

have a variable named obj
pass it as the last argument to a function
press tab (as I usually do) to come out of the parentheses
obj autocompletes to <object data="" type=""></object>

And this happens even if I pressed escape to close the autocomplete dropdown menu.
E.g.
function func(p) {}
const obj = {}
func(obj)

Copy paste this into an empty JS file in IntelliJ, put your caret behind obj on the last line and press tab.
How to disable this? And not only for obj but also for every other variable name this happens to.

I figured out that the solution is to go to settings > Editor > Live Templates and disable all the Zen templates (Zen CSS, Zen HTML, Zen XSL).
